# How can ctypes infer the types of integers that are passed?

Tags: python, ctypes, cdecl

I am interfacing this C code:

```
extern "C" void print_int(short a, int b, long c, long long d)
{
   printf("%hi %i %li %lli", a, b, c, d);
}
```

with this Python code:

```
from ctypes import *
lib=cdll.LoadLibrary("./libtest.so")
lib.print_int(1,2,3,4)
```

Even if I don't cast the arguments in `print_int` code, they are passed correctly and I get:

```
1 2 3 4
```

as expected. Why cannot *ctypes* do the same form floating-point numbers? The following snippet:

```
extern "C" void print_float(float a, double b, long double c)
{
   printf("%f %lf %Lf", a, b, c);
}
```

would require an explicit cast from *ctypes* otherwise an exception is raised.

```
lib.print_float(c_float(1.0), c_double(2.0), c_longdouble(3.0))
```

I am working in Unix, compiling with the *cdecl* calling convention if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because defaults and stack size.  If you don't specify the type, `ctypes` assumes `c_int`.  On a 64-bit system the stack is 64-bit, so shorts, ints, longs, long longs all are sign-extended and use a 64-bit stack slot.  `long long` would break on a 32-bit system.  `float` is a completely different binary format and is not compatible with `c_int`.

You can use `.argtypes` to specify the parameter types and then pass values normally.  Also `.restype` specifies the return value:

```
lib.print_float.argtypes = c_float,c_double,c_longdouble
lib.print_float.restype = None
lib.print_float(1,2,3)
```